# SalesForce Marketting cloud connector sendJunction

Tags: marketing-cloud

The marketing cloud connect installs an object called et4ae5__SendJunction__c that relates et4ae5__SendDefinition__c to Campaigns.

We can query the send junction directly; however, we cannot query the Send Junction from the et4ae5__SendDefinition__c in a nested query:

**Works**

```
Select Id, et4ae5__SendDefinition__c, et4ae5__SendDefinition__r.et4ae5__Business_unit__c FROM et4ae5__SendJunction__c
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM et4ae5__SendJunctions__r) FROM et4ae5__SendDefinition__c
```

We looked into the WSDL to see if we could identify the correct relationship name but the Send Definition object does not have a relationship field for the junction object underneath it.

It doesn't make sense that it would be a 1 way relationship. I can add the WSDL Definitions for the specified objects but they are quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get the correct name for the relationship:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM et4ae5__Campaigns__r) FROM et4ae5__SendDefinition__c
```

Determined by the fact that the related list name was Campaigns